# How to customise EKEventEditViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, eventkit

I am using default `EKEventEditViewController` in my App and I want to customize it, currently it shows all fields that came in default `EKEventEditViewController`, but I don't want to show URL field and also want to add  Timezone field. Can I do that and if yes then pleas let me know how can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can use this excerpt:

1) make your viewcontroller the delegate of your EKEventEditViewController

```
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
addController.delegate = self;
```

2) then implement this on your view controller:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) {
        UITableView *tableView = ((UITableViewController *)viewController).tableView;

    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
    {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]];

            NSLog(@"cell => %@, row => %d, section => %d", cell.textLabel.text, i, j);

            if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Calendar"]) {
                [cell removeFromSuperview];
            } else if(j == 5) { // If URL Field
                [cell removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Note: I found this in another Stackoverflow answer before and implemented it on my project. I forgot the link. Hope this helps and thanks to the original answer where I got this.

Comment: Thanks! It works for visible rows, if I scroll de tableView the rows appear again, maybe because of cellForRow method.. any other solution!? Thanks!

Comment: The cell logs (null) for those that don't initally show in the view. any fixes for this?