# How to modify EKEventEditViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, eventkit

I have integrated the eventKit framework and am using the EKEventEditViewController to organize the events, but I want to change its UI. See here:

[image: Default UI of EKEventEditViewController]

I want to add the two more fields to that view. One would be like the Title (Text Field) and other would be a drop down which would allow users to select the Type.

I googled a lot for this but I didn't find any reliable solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see this SO answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813240/how-to-customise-ekeventeditviewcontroller?rq=1
You may get an idea...