# Delete Rows (All-day,Repeat and URL) Permanetally From EKEventEditViewController

Tags: ios, ekeventstore, ekeventkit

I Create an Event on Calendar, so i used the code that was provided by Apple sample code and i use EkEventViewController, all do work fine.
but i want to customise EKEventViewController, and Delete these Rows -**All-day,Repeat and URL** when we create new Event view occurs.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813240/how-to-customise-ekeventeditviewcontroller
```

in this link i customise the EKEventEditViewController but when i refresh this view automatically these Rows are appearing.
so i want to permanently delete these ROWS.
please help me.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) {

    UITableView *tableView = ((UITableViewController *)viewController).tableView;

    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
    {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]];

            NSLog(@"cell => %@, row => %d, section => %d", cell.textLabel.text, i, j);

            if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Alert"]) {
                [cell removeFromSuperview];
            } else if(j == 5) { // If URL Field
                [cell removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and if i want to add new row than how i can add.

Comment: There are no properties mentioned by Apple for hiding those rows currently.

Comment: Srinivasan@ now what can i do for this.please help me.thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Not only that, but the answer given to your other question won't work in later versions of iOS.  Controllers like `EKEventEditViewController` are increasingly being implemented as remote view controllers which are controlled by a separate process and which cannot be modified from within your app.

Comment: simon@:when i refresh it than Row are visible on state.and thanks for answer